# Order DateTimeField by rounded time using only the ORM?

Tags: python, django

I came up with a solution but it's using a model method ( as far as i understand it cannot be used with `X.objects.filter()` ) and then use the python method `sorted`. I've read that it's way faster to use django ORM than direct python so I'm searching for a solution. I precise that adding fields to my model is not possible as the database is already well populated.
Basically I've an `Articles` model :

```
class Articles(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False)
    image = models.URLField(null=False, blank=False)
    summary = models.TextField()
    link = models.URLField(null=False, blank=False)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    source = models.ForeignKey(
        Sources, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="souurce")
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Categories)
```

and what I want to do is ordering result by approximate publication date ( for example an article published at 5:34 and an another one published a 5:31 are both considered published at the same time ), then I can perform other orderings like per category, source or even by title.

Here is my class method to do that (by closest 10 minutes ):

```
def get_approximate_date(self):
        pub_date = self.pub_date

        def timeround10(dt):
            """timertound closets 10 minutes"""
            a, b = divmod(round(dt.minute, -1), 60)
            h = (dt.hour + a) % 24
            m = b
            new = dt.replace(hour=h, minute=m, second=0, microsecond=0)
            return new

        return timeround10(pub_date)
```

Then in my view I can do the following ( I chose to order by approximate date then by reverse alphabetical order ) :

```
articles_ = Articles.objects.all()
articles_list = sorted(articles_, key=lambda i: (i.get_approximate_date(), i.summary), reverse=True)
```

The closest thing I came up with using only django ORM is :

```
Articles.objects.order_by("-pub_date__year","-pub_date__month","-pub_date__day","-summary")
```

Apart from being ugly it only round the pub date by hour, so 1:59 PM = 1:01PM.

I'm aware of `Trunc` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/database-functions/#trunc but it doesn't only implement a way to order by hour minutes etc, maybe i should expand it if it's the only option.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: why not just add 10 minutes up and filter by range

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean, how filtering by range could solve my problem ?

Comment: It is bit unclear what do you mean by filter as in your code you provided you are not filtering, filtering is making a query with an lookup for instance .filter(pub_date__range(somedatetime, somedatetime+timedelta(seconds=10) )

Comment: I made a mistake and wrote filter instead of order in my message as my snippets suggest, sorry for the disagreement